# Getting 'I18n::InvalidLocale · "ko" is not a valid locale' error when ko.yml is present and in the correct directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

When adding Korean to my app, I started getting I18n::InvalidLocale · "ko" is not a valid locale errors in staging. I have added a translation file named "ko.yml". It seems to work in development but not in staging.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I was getting this error because the parent key in the ko.yml file was "en:" and not "ko:". Updating the parent key in the file to match the filename fixed the error.

It was:

```
---
en:
  date:
    formats:
```

And this fixed it:

```
---
ko:
  date:
    formats:
```